# Why does this closure not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in a .js file:

```
ElegirRegion = function () {
    var pagina = $('#pagina').val();
    carousel.setPaginaActual(pagina);
    var x1 = $('#x1').val();
    var y1 = $('#y1').val();
    var x2 = $('#x2').val();
    var y2 = $('#y2').val();
    this.SeleccionInicial = function () {
        if (!(x1 == 0 && x2 == 0 && y1 == 0 && y2 == 0)) {
            var ias = $('img.imagen').eq(pagina).imgAreaSelect({ instance: true });
            ias.setSelection(x1, y1, x2, y2);
            ias.setOptions({ show: true });
            ias.update();
        }
    }
    //more stuff
}
$(document).ready(ElegirRegion);
```

And in the .html file code that calls the `SeleccionInicial` function:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    ElegirRegion.SeleccionInicial();
});
```

However, when I try to call `SeleccionInicial`, I get a SeleccionInicial is not a function error! Why isn't `SeleccionInicial` a closure?

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Comment: You will want to create an instance using `new ElegirRegion()`, otherwise `this` will be referring to the global window and not `ElegirRegion`.

Comment: http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

Comment: `this` will rarely refer to the `function` that's current executing. To define a method on a function object, refer to it by name in the assignment as well – `ElegirRegion.SeleccionInicial = ...;`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I meant the function that's currently executing (and have modified my comment to try to clarify that). `this` can refer to a different function, especially with `Function.prototype` methods, but `foo.call(foo)` is a rare and unusual use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're using `this` as though it reference `ElegirRegion`. But that's not what's happening.

```js
ElegirRegion = function() {
  console.log(this === ElegirRegion);
  console.log(this.toString());
  console.log(this === document);
};

$(document).ready(ElegirRegion);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The only way that would happen is if you were treating that function as a constructor (`ElegirRegion = new ...`). Instead, if you want to add a method to `ElegirRegion`, then reference it directly.

```js
ElegirRegion = function() {
  ElegirRegion.SeleccionInicial = function() {
    console.log('start');
  };
};

$(document).ready(ElegirRegion);

$(window).load(function() {
  ElegirRegion.SeleccionInicial();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If anything is unclear or inaccurate, I'd like to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem.